# How can I use std::string for Const Char Parameter

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the `std::rename()` function to move a `.docx` file, however, the name of the file may vary. How can I use a `std::string` within `std::rename()` so that it does not have to be a hardcoded filepath, like this `std::rename(filepath, destination);`?

Comment: [`std::string::c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)?

Comment: What is ```c_str```?

Comment: That's why it's a link.

Comment: Use `std::string strSample; strSample.c_str();`

Comment: Bookmarking that duplicate link for my own dupe-closing.

Comment: Consider using [`std::filesystem::rename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) instead of `std::rename()`, then you can pass `std::string` values without having to convert them to `char*` ([`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) can be constructed from `std::string`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you want to populate the strings in question, but here you go:

```
std::string fromName {"whatever you're going to do"};
std::string toName {"whatever you're going to do"};

std::rename(fromName.c_str(), toName.c_str());
```